# React reusable stateful component

Tags: reactjs, state

Let's say I created a component which can be turned on/off based on state.

```
var onOff = React.createElement(<OnOff />, mountElement);
onOff.setState({ on: false });
```

Later I'm creating a new component called Parent, which will use OnOff inside it.

```
render() { return <div><OnOff /></div> }
```

Now how can I change the OnOff state? There is no way I can call setState on it. And I should not according to React doc. So I have to add initial state to OnOff's props:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { on: props.initialOn };
}
```

then in Parent's render method, set the initialOn prop with its state:

```
render() { return <div><OnOff initialOn={false} /></div> }
```

But it's still not working, because whenever I change Parent's state, the OnOff component inside it is not re-created with new initial state. Instead, it is only re-rendered with old state. I have a CodePen to prove it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjMwjO?editors=101

Answer (score 2):

You can update the state of the OnOff component by declaring the update also inside a componentWillReceiveProps function, something like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps:  
  function(nextProps) { 
    this.setState({
      on : nextProps.initialOn
    });
}
```

This allows you to update state, when new props arrive. And it is valid react.

You should however consider if you need state in OnOff at all: if the only initial setting and all updates ONLY come from its parent component, then a stateless component would be better.

Comment: This seems to be a valid answer, I'll try it.

Comment: I found the official React doc that supports it: [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the important things to understand when "Thinking in React" is to figure out which component does State belong to.

Read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html) in React docs

> What Components Should Have State?
>
> Most of your components should simply take some data from props and render it. However, sometimes you
>   need to respond to user input, a server request or the passage of
>   time. For this you use state.
>
> Try to keep as many of your components as possible stateless. By doing
>   this you'll isolate the state to its most logical place and minimize
>   redundancy, making it easier to reason about your application.
>
> A common pattern is to create several stateless components that just
>   render data, and have a stateful component above them in the hierarchy
>   that passes its state to its children via props. The stateful
>   component encapsulates all of the interaction logic, while the
>   stateless components take care of rendering data in a declarative way.

Thus, your OnOff should not have state but use properties passed down from the parent instead. I have illustrated this at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaxbGm?editors=101

```
render() {
    writeLog("OnOff render called!")
    writeLog("Child: " + this.props.initialOn)
    return <span>{this.props.initialOn ? "On" : "Off"}</span>;
  }
```

I would also recommend reading "[Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)" to get further clarity.

Comment: Useful to point out that components preferably should not have state, but OP question is: given a stateful component, how can I update state after initial render..

Comment: I understand how most components should be stateless. However, the scenario is that I created OnOff first as a standalone stateful component. I used OnOff in an web app where it does not have a React owner or parent. It is mounted to a DOM element, and I can change its state easily when needed. Later, when creating another component, I realized that I can resue OnOff component, Also, it is possible that OnOff is provided by 3rd party library that I can't modify unless I fork the code.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.